# IntelliJ ignores gradle's global init.gradle file

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I'm using Windows. In my C:\Users\csaba.gradle\init.gradle file I have the following:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
          url "http://localhost:8082/artifactory/repo"
        }
    }
}
```

This should configure gradle to use the local .m2 repository and also Artifactory, which is running on my local host (basically a mirror).

When running Gradle from IntelliJ, this file is completely ignored. It keeps downloading files from the public repo over the internet.

What to do to make this work?

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot from "Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle"?

Comment: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/ZJLhuzW)

Comment: Please try to put init.gradle in GRADLE_HOME/init.d/ folder

Comment: Looks like the issue was I didn't have a GRADLE_HOME env parameter. After setting GRADLE_HOME in Env Variables and restarting IntelliJ, it finally started to download from my local Artifactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a GRADLE_HOME environment variable. The Gradle docs state that if this env variable is not set, it will default to the home dir, but looks like IntelliJ ignores it. Explicitly setting it solved the issue.